# Set the href of the submit input type

Tags: html

Could I have something like `<INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" NAME=submit VALUE=Submit>`, but instead of being a submit button, it could be an image? Is there something like `href`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML already got it:

```
 <input type="image" src="myimage.png" />
```

Clicking it is exactly like clicking a submit button, instead of `value` you define `src` and the coordinates of the click are also sent to the server.

[Official documentation](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.image.html).

**Edit** - while the form submission itself is the same, there is one difference between `<input type="submit" />` and `<input type="image" />` which is the value sent to the server for the clicked button. With ordinary submit button, the value of the button is sent alongside its name and can be then used to know if the form has been submitted, for example. In case of image input, each browser behaves differently, some send the value some send coordinates but you can't rely on this anymore. So, if you depend on the submitted button value in the server side code using image button is **not** good idea.

Answer (score 3):

The simplest way is to use an image as a submit button employing the  HTML form tag.

```
<input type="image" src="IMAGE.GIF" alt="Submit button">
```

However, you can also use Javascript for more robustness

```
<a href="javascript:document.your_form_name.submit()"> 
     <img src="IMAGE.gif" alt="Submit this form" name="sub_but" />
</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

`<input type="image" src="image.png" />` does exactly what you ask. You can't rely on the `name` attribute for it though (for example if your server-side code checks for it as a reference for the form being submitted), because the browser sends `name.x` and `name.y` for the coordinates clicked.

That aside, the `image` input type is essentially the same as a submit button for most purposes.

Comment: +1 for explaining about the `name` issue - forgot about that. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use image in place of showing default submit button.

```
 form input[type=submit] {
            background : url("submit.png") no-repeat center center;
            width : 115px; /* As per requirement */
        height :52px; /* As per requirement */
        border : none;
        color : transparent;
 }
```

Please note that type="image" support is lacking in some browsers so above mentioned styling is a safe way.

Comment: Input type="image" is very basic.. care to elaborate what browsers don't support it? Where did you see it?

Comment: I got vague impression about it. Please read http://www.sitepoint.com/forums/showthread.php?779391-Browsers-dropping-support-for-input-type-quot-image-quot

Comment: It matters only when the server side code is looking for the submitted code value e.g. `If Request("mysubmit")<>""` in classic ASP to check if the form was submitted. Not relevant here, but maybe I'll edit my post to be on the safe side. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this, in 'scr' you can put your image link; it would be like image button.

```
<input type="image" src="images/submit.jpg" value="Submit" alt="Submit">
```